# Handle file changes with i18next

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next

I'm using next.js with i18n and when I initialize my `i18n.js` , I'm loading the files with the translations files this way:

```js
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {defaultApplicationLocale} from '../application.properties'
var en_GB = require('./locales/EN/en-GB.json')
var pt_PT = require('./locales/PT/pt-PT.json')
var fr_FR = require('./locales/PT/fr_FR.json')

  const resources = {
    en_GB: {
      translation: en_GB
    },
    pt_PT: {
      translation: pt_PT
    },
    fr_FR:{
      translation: fr_FR
    }
  };

  i18n
    .use(initReactI18next) 
    .init({
      resources,
      lng: defaultApplicationLocale, 
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false 
      }
    });


export default i18n
```

Later I import this `i18n` already initialized and everything works fine.
But if I change one of the translation files (change some message from 'hi' to 'hello') it's doesn't work until I restart the whole thing. In theory `i18n` provides a function to reload resources `i18n.reloadResources()` which should reload the data from the files, but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using webpack, there is this HMR webpack plugin that allows reloading translation resources: https://github.com/felixmosh/i18next-hmr